# A string containing a character used for split

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to split values that are separated in commas but, there is a description containing a quote but the description is in quotes. I am trying to have the code ignore that part of the description and I've googled for solution but, came up empty.

Dim rowvalue As String
        Dim cellvalue(20) As String

```
    Dim streamReader As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader("C:\Me\Manifest_0001367051.csv")
    While streamReader.Peek() <> -1
        rowvalue = streamReader.ReadLine()
        cellvalue = rowvalue.Split(","c, """,""") 'check what is ur separator
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(cellvalue)

    End While
```

This is the value I am trying to break down

> OL-2G,0B1,1,1,"Sn, HP Cate",T:7051; C:KI; R:A; G:N; X:N; L:; UN:; ;
>   JP,AT,N,N,N

Answer (score 1):

Use the [right tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6.aspx).

String.Split is not up to the job of parsing csv.

`TextFieldParser` is made just for this.